# Interpreting type codes in sys.objects in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, types

On SQL Server, the sys.objects table includes "Type" and "Type_Desc" attributes. For example, for one of my DBs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Type], Type_Desc
FROM Sys.Objects
ORDER BY [Type]
```

Returns:

```
C       CHECK_CONSTRAINT  
D       DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT  
F       FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT  
FN      SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION  
FS      CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION  
IT      INTERNAL_TABLE  
P       SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE  
PK      PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT  
S       SYSTEM_TABLE  
SQ      SERVICE_QUEUE  
TR      SQL_TRIGGER  
U       USER_TABLE  
UQ      UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT  
V       VIEW
```

Different DBs have different results, depending on what types are used.

Is there a comprehensive list of these types somewhere? There isn't a constraint on sys.objects that points me to table of these, and sys.types contains data types. I've searched SQL BOL but haven't found it. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Some DBs use only a subset of these types. For example, if I have a database with no views, when I query Sys.Objects as above, there are no "V" rows in the results. I am looking for a list of all possible types and descriptions used by SQL Server.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

BOL has a complete list, but you can't join on that.

```
AF = Aggregate function (CLR)
C  = CHECK constraint
D  = DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)
F  = FOREIGN KEY constraint
FN = SQL scalar function
FS = Assembly (CLR) scalar-function
FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
IF = SQL inline table-valued function
IT = Internal table
P  = SQL Stored Procedure
PC = Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure
PG = Plan guide
PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint
R  = Rule (old-style, stand-alone)
RF = Replication-filter-procedure
S  = System base table
SN = Synonym
SQ = Service queue
TA = Assembly (CLR) DML trigger
TF = SQL table-valued-function
TR = SQL DML trigger
TT = Table type
U  = Table (user-defined)
UQ = UNIQUE constraint
V  = View
X  = Extended stored procedure
```

Going to the best SQL Server source for this info: [sys.objects (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) it doesn't mention any table to join to.  I can't say that I have ever noticed a codes table to join to for any of the systems tables or views.

I guess you'll have to create your own table or view, or just use the Type_Desc attribute in sys.objects.

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is a bit old now, but for those looking for an answer, this is what I found.

```
select * from master..spt_values where type = 'O9T'
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2016 this is new:

```
SP = Security Policy
```