# How to count total number of stored procedure and tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have database `Test1` in SQL Server 2008 R2. On the live server I took backup from there and restore it at our local machine as `Test2` and added some tables and procedures.

If we restore `Test2` back onto the live server so is it any query which can get tables name and procedure name which is only in test 2 not in test 1 or SQL Server treated it as totally different database?

And what is the query if I want to know only the number of difference of `Test1` and `Test2`  databases

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This will give you the count of tables and stored procedures.

```
SELECT 
    CASE TYPE 
        WHEN 'U' 
            THEN 'User Defined Tables' 
        WHEN 'S'
            THEN 'System Tables'
        WHEN 'IT'
            THEN 'Internal Tables'
        WHEN 'P'
            THEN 'Stored Procedures'
        WHEN 'PC'
            THEN 'CLR Stored Procedures'
        WHEN 'X'
            THEN 'Extended Stored Procedures'
    END, 
    COUNT(*)     
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE IN ('U', 'P', 'PC', 'S', 'IT', 'X')
GROUP BY TYPE
```

You can find in `sys.objects` all types of objects in the database. You will have to run this query on each of your databases to see the count of objects.

You can find all information about what is stored in `sys.objects` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx).

Comment: Aren't there are types than `P` that are stored-procedures like `PC`(Assembly [(CLR) stored-procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790(v=sql.105).aspx))?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was not aware of such, I will update my query.

Comment: `X` could be a stored proc as well - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907049/interpreting-type-codes-in-sys-objects-in-sql-server) related question for a list.

Comment: @Bridge I was just doing that :-)

Comment: If you have downvoted this answer while the majority upvoted it, I would be very curious as to what your reasons were. Then I might be able to improve my answer (which would help the community more than just a simple downvote).

Answer (score 16):

You can use those 2 queries:

```
select count(*) as TablesCount from sys.tables
select count(*) as ProceduresCount from sys.procedures
```

Answer (score 8):

I often use this script I found on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2007/09/24/script-of-the-day-count-all-objects-in-a-database.aspx?Redirected=true)

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
SELECT 'Count' = COUNT(*), 'Type' = CASE type 
                WHEN 'C' THEN 'CHECK constraints' 
                WHEN 'D' THEN 'Default or DEFAULT constraints' 
                WHEN 'F' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY constraints' 
                WHEN 'FN' THEN 'Scalar functions' 
                WHEN 'IF' THEN 'Inlined table-functions' 
                WHEN 'K' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints' 
                WHEN 'L' THEN 'Logs' 
                WHEN 'P' THEN 'Stored procedures' 
                WHEN 'R' THEN 'Rules' 
                WHEN 'RF' THEN 'Replication filter stored procedures' 
                WHEN 'S' THEN 'System tables' 
                WHEN 'TF' THEN 'Table functions' 
                WHEN 'TR' THEN 'Triggers' 
                WHEN 'U' THEN 'User tables' 
                WHEN 'V' THEN 'Views' 
                WHEN 'X' THEN 'Extended stored procedures' 
    END 

    FROM sys.objects 
    GROUP BY type 
    ORDER BY type 
GO
```

You can modify it by type from information about [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foof8d6163a-2474-410c-a794-997639f31b3b.aspx)

Or by object from this reference [Object Catalog Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx), as you already got an answer for tables and procedures in the previous answers, e.g.

```
SELECT count(*) AS MyTables FROM sys.tables
SELECT count(*) AS MyProcedures FROM  sys.procedures
SELECT count(*) AS MyTriggers FROM  sys.triggers
SELECT count(*) AS MyViews FROM  sys.views
```

Hope this gives you some additional help

Answer (score 5):

I now use the below, based on Milica's answer with some extra types, default value and sorted by count.

```
SELECT 'Count' = COUNT(*), 'Type' = CASE type 
    WHEN 'AF' THEN 'Aggregate function (CLR)' 
    WHEN 'C' THEN 'CHECK constraints' 
    WHEN 'D' THEN 'Default or DEFAULT constraints' 
    WHEN 'F' THEN 'FOREIGN KEY constraints' 
    WHEN 'FN' THEN 'Scalar functions' 
    WHEN 'FS' THEN 'Assembly (CLR) scalar-function' 
    WHEN 'FT' THEN 'Assembly (CLR) table-valued function' 
    WHEN 'IF' THEN 'Inlined table-functions' 
    WHEN 'IT' THEN 'Internal table' 
    WHEN 'K' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints' 
    WHEN 'L' THEN 'Logs' 
    WHEN 'P' THEN 'Stored procedures' 
    WHEN 'PC' THEN 'Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure' 
    WHEN 'PG' THEN 'Plan guide' 
    WHEN 'PK' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY constraint' 
    WHEN 'R' THEN 'Rules' 
    WHEN 'RF' THEN 'Replication filter stored procedures' 
    WHEN 'S' THEN 'System tables' 
    WHEN 'SN' THEN 'Synonym' 
    WHEN 'SO' THEN 'Sequence object' 
    WHEN 'SQ' THEN 'Service queue' 
    WHEN 'TF' THEN 'Table functions' 
    WHEN 'TR' THEN 'Triggers' 
    WHEN 'U' THEN 'User tables' 
    WHEN 'UQ' THEN 'UNIQUE constraint' 
    WHEN 'V' THEN 'Views' 
    WHEN 'X' THEN 'Extended stored procedures' 
    ELSE type
END 
FROM sys.objects 
GROUP BY type 
ORDER BY 'Count' desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following queries.

```
USE YOURDBNAME
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalTable from information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'base table'  

select Count(*) AS TotalProc from sys.procedures
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this script. It is not using switch case statement.

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
select distinct type_desc as 'Type Description', Count from
(SELECT 'Count' = COUNT(*), type FROM sys.objects GROUP BY type) as dbstatistics 
left join sys.objects on dbstatistics.type = sys.objects.type ORDER BY Count desc
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
SELECT 'Count' = COUNT(*),  'Object Description' = type_Desc
    FROM sys.all_objects
    GROUP BY type_Desc
    ORDER BY type_Desc
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers include a description of the code they contain.

Answer (score 0):

For number of tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sys.tables
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

OR

If you want to know number of tables in a particular schema(dbo) use:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

---

For Stored Procedures use:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) from sys.procedures
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';
```

Comment: Your query is only counting the number of tables for a specific schema.